# What type of array do I send to constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, client-server, chat

I am creating a server-chat-client application and have borrowed code. I know how most of the things work except one.

In my `Class Server` I wait for a socket to be accepted.

```
public static ArrayList<String> clientUsernameList = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int port = 8900;    //Port number the ServerSocket is going to use
    ServerSocket myServerSocket = null;  //Serversocket for sockets to connect
    Socket clientSocket = null;    //Listerner for accepted clients
    ClientThread[] clientsConnected = new ClientThread[20]; //Max clients in this server

    try {
        myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server waiting for clients on port:" + port);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    while (true) {            
        try {   //Freezes while-loop untill a socket have been accepted or if some failure occur
            clientSocket = myServerSocket.accept();                
            System.out.println("Client have connected from:" + clientSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostName());                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Print out exception
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        //For-loop that counts every element in Array-clientsConnected
        for (int i = 0; i < clientsConnected.length; i++) {
            //If-statement checks if current element is null 
            if(clientsConnected[i] == null){
                //If current element in the Array is null then create a new object from ClientThread class
                //With a socket and the object of itself as parameter.
                (clientsConnected[i] = new ClientThread(clientSocket, clientsConnected)).start();

                //Must have a break otherwise it will create 20 objects (Exit for-loop)
                break;
            }   //Exit if-statement
        }   //Exit for-loop
    }   //Exit while-loop

}
```

}

So if a socket gets accepted I create a thread class called `Class ClientThread`

To create a object of this class I need a socket and a array.
This is how my ClientThread class looks like

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {

private ClientThread[] clientsConnected;
private Socket SOCKET = null;
private DataInputStream IN = null;
private DataOutputStream OUT = null;
private String userName,zone;
//-------------------------------------------------------    
//Constructor
public ClientThread(Socket socket, ClientThread[] clientThread) {
    this.SOCKET = socket;
    this.clientsConnected = clientThread;
}
```

`//Some more code`

Now this is where I am lost. Do I send in my whole array? and if I do shouldn't user1 only get an array with 1 user and when user2 connects shouldn't he get an array with 2 users? I am lost. If someone could point me to something that explains this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code will serve only 20 requests. For each one it adds new value to clientsContected, once the whole table is full it will just go back to the start of the loop (without closing the accepted connection).
2. Probably the idea of passing the clientsConnected to the thread, was so it can set the value to null once it stopped working (so that your main code in the loop can assigne a new client to it). GUessin as no code is included). But for that an index inside the array would be useful (so 3 parameters instead of 2) so the ClientThread doesn't have to search the whole array to find object matching this.

I would rather recommend using BlockingQueue (with limited capacity for example 5) to which you will pass accepted connections. Once it is full your main will be forced to wait on it till it has same space to insert new connection so you will stop accepting new sockets. Create the 20 threads, that in a inifinite loop tries to get a socket from that queue and serve it. Once they finish they go back an wait for new request.

So yes you passs the whole array.

3. Still it doesn't solve the problem of what happens if all are busy, as you keep accepting new clients instead of waiting for free Thread.